# inconsistent pdf eps output: pst2pdf acting on original.tex vs pdflatex acting on pst2pdf original.tex->produced.tex(multiple)

Tags: pdftex, dvi, ps2pdf, pspicture

Following "The current state of pstricks project" (Herbet Voss, TUGboat, Vol31 (2101), no.1) I prepared a file unitz.tex containing 3 pspicture.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
%\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

%\newcommand\picwid{2.35}
%\newcommand\pichei{2.35}

\begin{document}
%\begin{pspicture*}(-\picwid,-\picwid)(\pichei,\pichei)
\begin{pspicture}   

   \rput(-2.0, 2.0){\psscalebox{1.0}{${\mathbb{C_{\mathbb{Q}}}}$}}

   \psaxes[linewidth=\linwid, ticks=none, labels=none, dx=1.0, dy=1.0]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$\Re$,0][$\Im$,90]


\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}  

   \rput(-2.0, 2.0){\psscalebox{1.0}{${\mathbb{C_{\mathbb{Q}}}}$}}

   \psaxes[linewidth=0.005pt, ticks=none, labels=none, dx=1.0, dy=1.0]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$\Re$,0][$\Im$,90]

\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}   
   \rput(-2.0, 2.0){\psscalebox{1.0}{${\mathbb{C_{\mathbb{Q}}}}$}}

   \psaxes[linewidth=0.005pt, ticks=none, labels=none, dx=1.0, dy=1.0]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$\Re$,0][$\Im$,90]

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The results were duly presented in images/. Unfortunately each of unitz-fig-n.pdf (n=1,2.3) slightly clipped \mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{Q}} placed at (2,2).

[image]

File unitz-fig-n.tex are also created in /images. To remedy the problem I ran pdflatex on each of theses files and subsequently pdf2ps and ps2eps, and the resulting files both pdf and eps were NOT clipped. I noted that unitz-fig-n.pdf files created by pst2pdf are overwritten without warning by pdflatex.

[image]

Note that, for clarity, I have removed everything in my original pspictures apart from axes and annotation.

```
pst2pdf unitz.tex -c -e
cd images/
pdflatex --shell-escape unitz-fig-1.tex
pdflatex --shell-escape unitz-fig-2.tex
pdflatex --shell-escape unitz-fig-3.tex
pdf2ps unitz-fig-1.pdf
ps2eps -f unitz-fig-1.ps
pdf2ps unitz-fig-2.pdf
ps2eps -f unitz-fig-2.ps
pdf2ps unitz-fig-3.pdf
ps2eps -f unitz-fig-3.ps
```

I am puzzled. Why does the pst2pdf clip, while producing .tex files that produce unclipped images by pdflatex. I might also have tried pst2pdf on its own .tex output. I am fascinated but exhausted.

This has followed weeks of experimenting, following the LaTeX->dvips -e route as originally I was happy with eps. All files were clipped or resulted in absurd white space regions. I believed that bounding boxes should find the smallest rectangular region that will contain all postscript creations. I used GS which tried to help by adjusting bounding boxes but to no avail. I tried GS pdf round-tripping without success (LaTeX eps approach).

```
latex unitz.tex 
dvips -o unitz.ps unitz.dvi
ps2eps -g -f unitz.ps
gs -o so#126826212.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dEPSCrop unitz.ps
gs -o unitz.roundtripped.eps -sDEVICE=eps2write so#126826212.pdf
```

I should also point out that I have no clear understanding of how latex produces the dvi file. Do I actually need pspicture (if a file only contains one graphic). My preference is to start with an origin in my model of the world and create pstricks objects relative to that. I do not really mind wrapping the things in a pspicture (of course if there is more than one) but I object to having to set the size of the pspicture. You will see in the attached file that I have experimented with different sizes of pspicture but have still obtained superfluous white space. I have not found any pstricks documentation that discusses this.

Comment: The problem itself is not `pst2pdf` but rather the drawing area of the environments, if you use [showgrid=true] and adjust it well, the script does the right thing

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is what I wish to avoid. I recall from documentation that it is not necessary and indeed this is demonstrated above. But I do not understand why.

Comment: I understand, maybe I expressed myself wrong, the point is that you must express a BB box size (that includes at least the size of the drawing) otherwise the cut won't fit well

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze a little your MWE, I modified the class to `article`, commented the package `auto-pst-pdf` and changed the line 21 to `linewidth=0.005pt`, added the word `TEXT` between the environments and `[showgrid=true]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
%\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

%\newcommand\picwid{2.35}
%\newcommand\pichei{2.35}

\begin{document}
TEXT
%\begin{pspicture*}(-\picwid,-\picwid)(\pichei,\pichei)
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true]

   \rput(-2.0, 2.0){\psscalebox{1.0}{${\mathbb{C_{\mathbb{Q}}}}$}}

   \psaxes[linewidth=0.005pt, ticks=none, labels=none, dx=1.0, dy=1.0]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$\Re$,0][$\Im$,90]


\end{pspicture}
TEXT
\begin{pspicture}  

   \rput(-2.0, 2.0){\psscalebox{1.0}{${\mathbb{C_{\mathbb{Q}}}}$}}

   \psaxes[linewidth=0.005pt, ticks=none, labels=none, dx=1.0, dy=1.0]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$\Re$,0][$\Im$,90]

\end{pspicture}
TEXT
\begin{pspicture}   
   \rput(-2.0, 2.0){\psscalebox{1.0}{${\mathbb{C_{\mathbb{Q}}}}$}}

   \psaxes[linewidth=0.005pt, ticks=none, labels=none, dx=1.0, dy=1.0]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$\Re$,0][$\Im$,90]

\end{pspicture}
TEXT
\end{document}
```

When you compile the document using `latex>dvips>ps2pdf`  the first page looks like:
[image: first page]

If you look, the words `TEXT` should be in another position (and not on the drawing), this happens because the `pspicture` environment should carry the argument `(x,y)` or `(x1,y1)(x2,y2)`.
By omitting it and using `pst2pdf` or `auto-pst-pdf`these call the `pdfcrop` script to crop the image, but, it is not generated correctly.

Adding this argument would make the code look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
%\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand\picwid{2.35}
\newcommand\pichei{2.35}

\begin{document}
TEXT
%\begin{pspicture*}(-\picwid,-\picwid)(\pichei,\pichei)
\begin{pspicture}(-\picwid,-\picwid)(\pichei,\pichei)

   \rput(-2.0, 2.0){\psscalebox{1.0}{${\mathbb{C_{\mathbb{Q}}}}$}}

   \psaxes[linewidth=0.005pt, ticks=none, labels=none, dx=1.0, dy=1.0]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$\Re$,0][$\Im$,90]


\end{pspicture}
TEXT
\begin{pspicture}(-\picwid,-\picwid)(\pichei,\pichei)

   \rput(-2.0, 2.0){\psscalebox{1.0}{${\mathbb{C_{\mathbb{Q}}}}$}}

   \psaxes[linewidth=0.005pt, ticks=none, labels=none, dx=1.0, dy=1.0]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$\Re$,0][$\Im$,90]

\end{pspicture}
TEXT
\begin{pspicture}(-\picwid,-\picwid)(\pichei,\pichei)
   \rput(-2.0, 2.0){\psscalebox{1.0}{${\mathbb{C_{\mathbb{Q}}}}$}}

   \psaxes[linewidth=0.005pt, ticks=none, labels=none, dx=1.0, dy=1.0]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$\Re$,0][$\Im$,90]

\end{pspicture}
TEXT
\end{document}
```

Now, when you run `pst2pdf -e test.tex` the output `test-pdf.pdf` is the expected one along with the images in `.eps` format.
[image: output_ok]

Comment: Pablo, I am returning to this after some time and I cannot recall all the paths I took. Yet I posted since I was able to produce the way I wished I just had to find the correct procedure as I described. This I obtained by brute force not insight. I do not know where all this is documented and until then I remain unenlightened. You say "not generated correctly" do you mean the software is in error or that therefore does not generate correctly?

Comment: When I say "not generated correctly" I mean that the bbox of the generated drawing is not the expected one (it is the default box if you don't pass parameters), it is in the documentation of `pstricks` (V Picture Tools, p40)